# Why does the JavaScript Promise not work on Android 4.4 using the Ionic Framework?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

i am using ionic + firebase to make a chatting application. When a message comes to the phone, it comes with uid, i need to fetch username with that uid to show user the message (username:messagetext). But fetching username from firebase directly takes time(and bandwith). So i need to cache these uid:username pairs. System i wrote works on website and android emulator. But when i try to install it on my android phone it does not work. Here is the code.

```
  var uNameCache = {};
  function getUsername(uid) {
    toastr.info("Fetching username for "+uid);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      toastr.info("Trying to fetch with a promise");//this is not showing on an actual android phone
      if(uNameCache[uid]){
        //get from cache
        toastr.info("get from cache");
        resolve(uNameCache[uid]);
      }else{
        //get from firebase
        toastr.info("get from firebase");
        firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
          var username = snapshot.val().username;
          uNameCache[uid] = username;
          resolve(username);
        });
      }
      //resolve("High_Admin");      
      // reject ("Error!");
    });
  };
```

and here is the code that uses this

```
firebase.database().ref('channel_messages').child(channelid).on('child_added',function(snapshot){
    var msg = snapshot.val();
    toastr.info("message get");
    getUsername(msg.uid).then(function(username){
      toastr.info("username fetched!");
      msg.username = username;
      $scope.messages.push(msg);
      //todo if scrollplace down scroll down, else dont touch player is reading old messages.
      $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollBottom();
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  });
```

edit: I am still not sure why this happened but i find a shortcut by just deleting promise and dealing it on firebase event.

Comment: May I use why you are using the Javascript Promise and not the Angular promise? And which version of Android is your device running?

Comment: I didnt knew there was Angular Promise, sure will look at that.
And i did tested this code on android kitkat (not really sure which version exactly)
Thanks for info. Have a great day ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this may be due to the fact that older versions of Android do not supports JavaScript Promises. You can check such things on [this website](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises).

The big difference is that the Angular Promise is called `$q`, but other than that you won't notice that many differences. You can find a lot more information about it in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

In your code, you need to inject `$q` as a dependency and change:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
```

To this:

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
```